# Magento 2 how to add product attribute of type textarea with editor programmatically

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, programmatically, wysiwyg

How can we add custom attribute using setup script in magento 2

attribute type should be textarea with editor.

Like Product description.

Comment: Can refer `vendor\magento\module-cms\Setup\InstallSchema.php`

Answer (score 11):

I have use this script to add custom attribute in products.

It's working fine for me.

```
/** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
 $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

 /**
 * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
 */

$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'shop_by_brand',
        [
            'type' => 'text',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Shop by Brand',
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => true,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => true,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'is_wysiwyg_enabled'      => TRUE,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

Comment: backend appears twice, and second time with ArrayBackend

Answer (score 2):

It's working fine for me.

```
$eavSetup->addAttribute(
Product::ENTITY,
'custom_attribute',
[
    'group' => 'Product Details',
    'type' => 'text',
    'backend' => '',
    'frontend' => '',
    'label' => 'Custom Attribute',
    'input' => 'textarea',
    'class' => '',
    'source' => '',
    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
    'visible' => true,
    'required' => true,
    'user_defined' => false,
    'default' => '',
    'searchable' => false,
    'filterable' => false,
    'comparable' => false,
    'visible_on_front' => false,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true,
    'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
    'unique' => false,
    'apply_to' => ''
]
);
```

Comment: wysiwyg_enabled appears twice in your array

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
$eavSetup = $this->_eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

$eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'size_n_fit');

$eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'size_n_fit',
    [
        'group' => 'Custom Attribute',
        'type' => 'text',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Size And Fit',
        'input' => 'textarea',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => '',
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => ''
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 0):

the option is_wysiwyg_enabled is setted in table catalog_eav_attribute,
so you can create model Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute and effect is_wysiwyg_enabled as 1

```
/** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);


        $eavResult = $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE,
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'More Description',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'backend' => '',
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => false,
                'default' => 0,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => true,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => true,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'is_wysiwyg_enabled'      => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'group' => 'content'
            ]
        );

        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $catalogAttributeModel */
        $catalogAttributeModel = $this->attributeFactory->create();
        $catalogAttributeModel->load($eavResult->getAttributeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE));
        $catalogAttributeModel->setData("is_wysiwyg_enabled",1)->save();
```